# Console outputs gibberish code after re-redirecting stdout to CON

Tags: c++, encoding, console, stdout, freopen

When I use C++ to invoke Python program output (By system command with parameters), it outputs gibberish code at the end of line. After that, I couldn't input any character (Include Backspace and Enter), it displays a hollow square.

Console screenshot:

[image]

Whole function code: (Uses file process)

```cpp
freopen("WCH_SYSTEM.tmp", "w", stdout);
system(("TRANS -i \"" + str + "\" > WCH_TRANS.tmp").c_str());
freopen("CON", "w", stdout);
Sleep(500);
ifstream fin("WCH_TRANS.tmp");
fin >> info;
cout << info << endl;
DeleteFile("WCH_SYSTEM.tmp");
```

Comment: it seems the console is using ANSI, you may try the command `chcp 65001`

Comment: @Rratic This command makes all Enter display like a hollow square...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After repeated inspection, I have found that `freopen()` can cause these encoding problems.

You can redirect the output of the function (NOT FREOPEN!!!) to a temporarily file like this.

DO NOT USE FREOPEN LIKE THIS! THIS MAY CAUSE UNEXPECTED BEHAVIOR.

```cpp
freopen("CON", mode, handle);
```

This is correct:

```cpp
system(("TRANS -i \"" + str + "\" > WCH_TRANS.tmp").c_str());
Sleep(500);
ifstream fin("WCH_TRANS.tmp");
fin >> info;
cout << info << endl;
DeleteFile("WCH_TRANS.tmp");
```

I'm using TDM-GCC64 on Windows, maybe this issue only appear on this compiler.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try UTF-8?
Maybe the python's character is diffrent from cpp.

Comment: This should not be in the answer section.

Comment: I have tried both (None UTF-8 & UTF-8).